# Python Pandas IF AND statement

Tags: python, pandas

This may seem like a very simple question but I'm having difficulties in adding a if and statement for python pandas. This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ["True","False","False","True"],
    'C2':  ["True","True","False","True"],
})
print(df)
```

I am looking to create a new column named C3 in my data frame. This column will say 'True' if if the corresponding values on the same row for columns C1 and C2 are 'True'
as well. And if the values on the same row both are not true for columns C1 and C2 then the value in C3 will say 'False'.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def apply_func(df):
    val1 = True if df.C1 == "True" else False
    val2 = True if df.C2 == "True" else False
    return val1 and val2

df["C3"] = df.apply(apply_func, axis=1)
```

You can use a function to handle the values. I had to convert the strings to boolean values before using them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['C3'] = df['C1'].eq('True') & df['C2'].eq('True')

      C1     C2     C3
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
3   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Convert string to boolean for ease of operation:

```
df['C3'] = df.apply(pd.eval).all(axis=1).astype(str)
```

Or,

```
df['C3'] = df.replace({'True': True, 'False': False}).all(axis=1).astype(str)
```

Finally, convert back to string for the desired string results.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      C1     C2     C3
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
3   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ["True","False","False","True"],
    'C2':  ["True","True","False","True"],
})
df['C3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['C2'] == "True" and row['C1'] == "True", axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [pandas.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.Series.where)?.

```
mask = df['C1'].eq('True') & df['C2'].eq('True')
df['C3'] = df['C1'].where(cond=mask, other='False')
```

Output:

```
     C1      C2      C3
0   True    True    True
1   False   True    False
2   False   False   False
3   True    True    True
```